# Delete a sub menu from a commandbar

Tags: vba, excel

I created a sub menu in excel vba on my Data Table. Here is the code,

```
Set cbut = Application.CommandBars("List Range Popup").Controls("Delete")
With cbut.Controls.Add
    .Caption = "Now"
End With
```

My question is, how do i delete this submenu named "Now" from the "Delete" commandbar instead of deleting the "Delete" commandbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about using `object variable`?

*(solution not tested- rather pseudo-code below)*

```
dim subButton as commandbarbutton 'or any other 
set subbutton = cbut.controls.add

with subbutton
    .caption = "now"
end with
'.... other actions
subbutton.delete
```

Answer (score 0):

It should simply be:

```
Application.CommandBars("List Range Popup").Controls("Delete").Controls("Now").Delete
```